# yii2 adding extra language

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks

I tried many times to add extra language for yii2 basic template and I have been failing in all them, let me show you all my codes and could you please help me to fix my error, actually the site does not say any error, everything is working smoothly but the language is not being switched to another

-----config/web.php----

```
'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
    return [
    // set target language to be Russian
    'language' => 'ru-RU',

    // set source language to be English
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',


];

    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                //'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                //'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'qwdqdq',
        ],
```

messages/ru-RU/app.php

```
<?php

return [
    'welcome' => 'Добро пожаловать',
    'log in' => 'Войти',
    'This is a string to translate!' => 'Это строка для перевода'
    //...
];
```

----------siteController.php-------

```
Class SiteController extends Controller
{


    public function actionChangeLang($local) 
{
    $available_locales = [
        'ru-RU',
        'en-US'
    ];    

    if (!in_array($local, $available_locales)) {
        throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException();
    }

    \Yii::$app->language = $local;

    retur
```

n $this->goBack();
}

view file----- site/index.php

Comment: This is because you set language just for current instance. When you return $this->goBack() an redirect is made and a new instace of Yii::$app is created with default language that is set in config

Comment: The better way to do is to set a cookie and check it before any request is made and set the language

Answer (score 0):

In your config/web.php add 'on beforeAction' like fallowing

```
return [
    'id' => 'basic',    
    // set target language to be Russian
    'language' => 'ru-RU',
    // set source language to be English
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',

    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
      ...
    ],
    'params' => [
       ...
    ],
    'on beforeAction' => function(){
        // get language from cookie, session or db 
        // and set it to app language
        Yii::$app->language = isset($_COOKIE['language'])?$_COOKIE['language']:Yii::$app->language;
    }
];
```

In your SiteControler function actionChangeLang replace line

```
 \Yii::$app->language = $local;
```

with

```
setcookie("language", $local);
```

Now you will be able to change your locale and keep it between requests.
In my example I used cookies but you also may use any type of storage to store your locale.